# Order of derivatives, moving terms past operators

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having trouble understanding the following progression of equalities.

$\begin{align*}
\ddot{x} &= \frac{dv}{dt}\\
&= \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}\\
&= v \frac{dv}{dx} \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{dv^2}{dx} \tag{2}
\end{align*}$

I understand up to $(1)$. In the previous line, I realize that $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, but shouldn't $(1)$ have then been $\frac{dv}{dx} v$? Why is it acceptable to move $v$ to the left side of the differential; $v$ depends on $x$ and so will be operated on by it, won't it?

Accepting $(1)$, I don't understand how to get to $(2)$. I expect it has something to do with integrating $v$ so it can be moved to the right side; that would account for the $\frac{1}{2}$ and $v^2$, but I don't know the principle that makes $\frac{dv}{dx} v^2 = \frac{dv^2}{dx}$.

Trying to reach conceptual understanding by substituting in an example term, I do this, where $v=x^2$
$\begin{align*}
v \frac{d}{dx}v &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} v^2\\
(x^2)(2x) &= \frac{1}{2} (4x^3)\\
2x^3 &= 2x^3
\end{align*}
$

I see that they are equal, but I don't understand. With my reasoning about the integration, this would have happened

$
\begin{align*}
v \frac{d}{dx} v &= \frac{d}{dx}v \frac{1}{2}v^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} v^3
\end{align*}
$

which does not give equal answers.

Hopefully I've made my deficit of knowledge obvious and someone can prod me helpfully in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read

$$\begin{align*}
\ddot{x} &= \frac{dv}{dt}\\
&= \left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right).\left( \frac{dx}{dt}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right).(v)\\
&=(v).\left(\frac{dv}{dx}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{dv^2}{dx}\right)
\end{align*},$$
where the dots denote ordinary product.

The last step is indeed obtained from $df(v)=f'(v).dv$, i.e. $dv^2=2v.dv$.